# No forking observed with surefire 2.16 despite forkCount being > 1

Tags: maven, junit, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

Here is my setting:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>1C</forkCount>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-Xmx256m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And I'm using junit 4.12:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when launching my tests I can't see any forking going on?
I'm using maven 3.2.5 on linux with JDK 8.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a little debug (`mvn -X test`) and it turns out that despite using version 4.12 surefire isn't using the `junit47` provider, but the `junit4` provider. Unfortunately the `junit4` provider does not seem to handle `forkCount`.

Crawling through the documentation I could find the following algo that selects the provider : https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html
The `parallel` attribute must be set in order to activate the `junit47` provider (a little counter-intuitive...).

I've created a JIRA for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1171

Now my config looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                <forkCount>1C</forkCount>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-Xmx256m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

### Edit

Turns out, `redirectTestOutputToFile` is now rendered useless... I've added a comment to an existing issue : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-703?focusedCommentId=14653289&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14653289

I came up with the following to have both forks and `redirectTestOutputToFile` work:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>1C</forkCount>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```